# Latex command \lll or \ggg not working

Tags: math-mode, equations

I'm trying to write ">>>" using the command "\ggg" or "\lll". Here is list of the packages I'm using:

```
\usepackage{cite,graphicx,amssymb,amsmath,psfrag,bm}    
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,table,xcdraw]{xcolor}    
\usepackage{mathabx}    
\usepackage{array}    
\usepackage{hyperref}    
\usepackage{cancel}    
\usepackage{epstopdf}    
\usepackage{rotating}    
\epstopdfsetup{update}    
\usepackage{pstool}    
\usepackage{multirow}    
\usepackage{color}    
\usepackage{soul}    
\usepackage{fullpage}    
\usepackage{bibentry}
\usepackage{caption}    
\usepackage{subcaption}
```

But this is what I get at the end: [image]

I really appreciate for any help.

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) package list does not help us much. Please make this a full minimal example. (3) where have you read that there exists a `\ggg` macro? Stat should probably also tell you which package provides it. (4) exactly which error do you get?

Comment: @daleif `amssymb` defines a `\ggg`, see e.g. `texdoc symbols-a4` table 123.

Comment: Do you need the `mathabx` package? It redefines many math symbols, and removing that will likely give you what you're after.

Comment: Actually, I guessed that it is the package problem, and it really was. I didn't get error, instead of ">>>" it was typing a wrong symbol as can be seen in the picture. Thanks to Guuk the problem is solved now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add the `MnSymbol` package using `\usepackage{MnSymbol}` and remove `\usepackage{mathabx}`.

The list of symbols could be found [here](http://tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf).

Comment: Mnsymbol should probably be avoided unless you are using a math font that suits it.

Comment: Yes, great and thanks a lot. This works :) :)